# PHP class has two methods with different parameters, how to take advantage of the constructor?

Tags: php

I want to make a class let's say it's called validation, it has two functions, either `registrationVal` or `loginVal`.

I want to pass data from two different pages that will use the same class. I want to initialize the variables in a constructor so it looks cleaner... how can I do this?

How can I call the constructor from one page when it doesn't have all the variables to be passed to the constructor?

For example:

*registration page*

```php
$obj = new validation($password, $password2, $email, $phone);
$obj->registrationVal();
```

*login page*

```php
$obj = new validation($email, $password);
$obj->loginVal();
```

Comment: _...i want to initialize the variables in a constructer so it looks cleaner..._ In your case you should use setters instead. You could also define a constructor which gets ($email, $password); and use setter methods for the rest. Php doesn't allow different sets of constructors,

Comment: Pass them to `registrationVal` and `loginVal` not the constructor.

Comment: _...Pass them to registrationVal and loginVal..._ Indeed much much better @AbraCadaver

Comment: will do then, thank you

Comment: If you're set on using a class for this, I'd suggest passing `$email` and `$password` to the constructor. Since `registrationVal()` relies on the password parameters, I'd pass those 2 variables to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can make something like this. It's not the best code - but for start is not bad.

```
<?php

class Validator
{
    private array $params;
    private array $validated = [];
    private array $errors = [];

    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        $this->params = $params;
        $this->validate();
    }

    private function validate(): void
    {
        foreach ($this->params as $field => $param){
            $validationMethod = 'validate' . ucfirst(strtolower($field));
            if(! method_exists($this, $validationMethod)){
                continue;
            }
            if($error = $this->{$validationMethod}($param)){
                $this->errors[$field] = $error;
            }else{
                $this->validated[$field] = $param;
            }
        }
    }

    public function validateOrFail(): void
    {
        if($this->hasErrors()){
            throw new ValidationException($this->getErrors());
        }
    }
    
    public function validated(): array
    {
        return $this->validated;
    }

    private function validateLogin($value): ?string
    {
       //validation logic - return null on success or error string
        return $validation_result;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->params[$name] ?? null;
    }

    public function getErrors(): array
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }

    public function hasErrors(): bool
    {
        return count($this->errors) > 0;
    }
}
```

You must write validation methods such validateLogin() for login field or validatePassword() for password field.

How it working:

```
$params = [
  'login' => 'login',
  'password' => 'password'
  ...
];
$validator = new Validator($params);
//it will throw exception when validation failing.
$validator->validateOrFail();
//or you can manually working with errors
if($validator->hasErrors()){
  ...
}
$password = $validator->password;

//or you can get only validated fields
$params = $validator->validated();
```